# How does this protective circuit work?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, battery-charging, dc

Below is a circuit which I found that is used for protective earth neutral detection.

The PEN_ON comes from MCU and PEN_dET goes to an MCU.

P20 is a current transformer.

[image]

Can someone explain how this circuit works and why it is required?

This is an application of an EV charger module which takes mains input and then meters, then  AC charger the EV battery. Between the AC main and EV charger connector, where would this CT come? There's a relay (which is controlled by an MCU) in the line between AC main and connector.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a half-wave rectifier and filter (U9A, through D9 and the 10uF cap) going to comparator (U9B), that changes state when voltage is above its reference (around 0.55V).
D5 is there for some form of protection to the input, but even without the details on how it's connected outside I would have some concern in case of a real PE fault - a fault line voltage would blow it and all its small friends in a snap.